# python regular expression(re) - how to extract this?

Tags: python, parentheses

```
import re
a = re.search('2(34)', '1234134').group()
print(a)
```

I expected this output:

```
34
```

but I got this:

```
234
```

how can I extract only 34 next to 2, not 34 next to 1?

Comment: Use `a = re.search('2(34)', '1234134').group(` **1** `)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
re.search('2(34)', '1234134').group(1)
```

output:

```
34
```

you can read more about grouping [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping)

Comment: @monsoon Welcome, you can accept the answer if this fix your issue